# Where do I find more information about using Claws Mail combined with Tails and OpenPGP?

Tags: tails, email

Where do I find more information about using Claws Mail combined with Tails and OpenPGP?

There is only a detailed howto for Pidgin available on the Tails website.
But for Claws Mail, one can find nearly nothing about how to use it with Tails and OpenPGP.